# passing a promise to resolve in Angular

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-ui-router, resolve

So i am trying to pass the promise from a http request to a resolve which would then only when received load a view. I am wondering where the mistake is here as i get a Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]  error. The "mainsearch" controller is the controller where state.go is defined and not the controller for the template. I am not sure if that causes an issue.

```
//in app.js
  .state({
                name: "mainSearch",
                url: "/mainSearch",
                views: {
                    'testView': {
                        template: '<div><span>{{params}} , I load after the promise</span></div>',
                        controller: "mainSearch",
                    }
                },
                resolve: {
                    entityParams: ['$stateParams', 'mainSearch', function ($stateParams) {        console.log("I load before the view as i contain a promise")
                        return $stateParams
                    }]
                }

            })

    // in mainSearch.js 
    state.go("mainSearch", {
            params: httpfactory.getResult('GET', param)
          })


// in http-factory module
    var app = angular.module("http-factory", []);

    app.factory('httpfactory', ['$http', function ($http) {

        $scope.getResult = function (callType, param) {
            switch (callType) {
                case 'POST':
                    $http.post('/abcurl', 'requestBody', {
                        withCredentials: true,
                        headers: {
                            "abc": "abc"
                        }
                    })
                    break;

                case 'GET':
                    return $http.get('/gttportal/api/search', {
                        params: param,
                        withCredentials: true
                    })

            }
            break;
        }
    }]);
```

this is how i have my app.js and module congifured

```
app = angular.module('myapp', ['http-factory','mainsearch']
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, httpfactory) {...
```

this  is how i have my mainsearch module and function configured:

```
 .module('mainsearch', ['http-factory'])

function ($rootScope, $scope, $http, $state,  $stateParams, httpfactory)
```

Comment: In your resolve, you have entityParams: ['$stateParams', 'mainSearch' ... but you don't have mainSearch as an argument to the function. So I'd suggest remove the 'mainSearch' before the function.

Comment: @rrd thanks, that did not solve the issue though

Comment: @rrd any other idea?

Comment: In your factory, you need [] around the first $http and the ending ), for the injection.

Comment: @rrd didnt help.... :(